# How to add 'virtual' audio input device / microphone programmatically in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, microphone, low-level

I already created a program that reads audio from selected input (using waveIn winApi functions from mmeapi.h), processes it in custom pipeline and passes to selected output.

What I want to do is add custom input device, (virtual microphone let's say) and pass my processed audio data to it. Make it visible in windows as microphone and be accessible for other programs.

The target is to modify my voice, increase quality, reduce noise, add some effects etc. and be able to use it in Microsoft Teams or Discord.

Is adding custom virtual microphones programmatically possible at all? And if so I need some MSDN references or header names or winApi function names. I was looking for them but I didn't find.

I don't want to use any external libraries.

Comment: Are the [samples](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da18a11e-a632-4dcd-a45e-59c5001ac726/virtual-microphone-driver-sample?forum=wdk) on MSDN forum helpful to you?

Comment: Looks good, thank you. But I think it's not enough.